# Datatype mismatch in criteria expression, ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wrote this query

```
SELECT dayar 
FROM   dayarim 
WHERE  ( Year(enter_month) = Year(Now()) ) 
    OR ( Year(enter_month) < Year(Now()) 
         AND Year(left_month) >= Year(Now()) ) 
       AND ( Datediff('m', Iif(Year(enter_month) = Year(Now()), enter_month, 
                                 '1/1/' + Year(Now())), Now()) * 50 ) < ( 
           Datediff('m', '1/1/' + Year(Now()), Now()) * 50 )
```

And I get this error:

> Datatype mismatch in criteria expression

I search in google and I found that this error means that the equal to expression dosen't match to the field data type

My table:

https://i.gyazo.com/3b1b3a4e948c3ebdd0054c8db4fc7516.png

My data:

https://i.gyazo.com/7c52b15914873e5c2eac3f704b156a90.png

I'm trying to achive list of names that didn't paid
They need to pay 50 every month, So a result will be list of names that didnt paid

**EDIT**
Because of Gustav comment I understand that I ddint check the sum they paid

```
 SELECT dayar 
 FROM   dayarim 
 WHERE  ( Year(enter_month) = Year(Now()) ) 
    OR ( Year(enter_month) < Year(Now()) 
         AND Year(left_month) >= Year(Now()) ) 
       AND (SELECT Sum(payments.sum) 
            FROM   payments 
            WHERE  payments.paymentdate > '1/1' + Year(Now()) 
                   AND paymentdate <= Now() 
                   AND payerid = dayarim.id) < ( 
           Datediff('m', '1/1/' + Year(Now()), Now()) * 50 );
```

But still get the same error

Comment: You seem to have everything mixed up regarding dates and years and misuse of text in a very convoluted way. What are you trying to accomplish, please?

Comment: @Gustav , I try to achive the pepole didn't paid from start of the year until the current month

Comment: But what is `enter_month` and `left_month`? Date, year, or?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Gustav Date/time , look at my edit, I post the table structure

Comment: @GordonLinoff look at my edit please

Comment: OK, but what indicates if people have paid (and when) or not?

Comment: @Gustav look at my edit again, I forgot about this part, I fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT 
    dayar 
FROM   
    dayarim 
WHERE
   Year(Nz(left_month, Date())) >= Year(Date())
   AND
   Year(enter_month) <= Year(Date()) 
   AND
   (SELECT Sum(payments.sum) 
    FROM   payments 
    WHERE  Year(payments.paymentdate) = Year(Date())
        AND payerid = dayarim.id) < (Month(Date()) - 1) * 50
```

Comment: it's not throw any error but also don't working properly , I will paste my solution now that friend help me

Answer (score 0):

the correct query is:

```
SELECT dayar 
FROM   dayarim 
WHERE  ( Year(enter_month) = Year(Now()) ) 
    OR ( Year(enter_month) <= Year(Now()) 
         AND Year(left_month) = Year(Now()) ) 
       AND (SELECT Sum(payments.sum) 
            FROM   payments 
            WHERE  payments.paymentdate > Dateserial(Year(Now()), 1, 1) 
                   AND paymentdate <= Now() 
                   AND payerid = dayarim.id) < ( Datediff('m', 
                                                 Dateserial(Year(Now( 
                                                 )), 
                                                 1, 1), Now()) * 50 );
```

I just replace the bilding of dates with DateSerial function and its works

Thanks to Joe4